# Global constant initialized at runtime in Rust?

Tags: rust, global-variables, constants

Is is possible to define a global constant, value of which is computed at the beginning of the runtime? Something like

```
static START_TIME: time::Timespec = time::get_time();
```

if it were possible. `static` and `const` declaration requires compile time value (`calls in constants are limited to struct and enum constructors`) and let can't be put outside function (`` error: expected item, found `let` ``).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think something like [lazy_static](http://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/lazy-static.rs/lazy_static/index.html) can help with this.

Comment: Since this answer 3 years passed... There is still no better way how to do this? Can't believe Rust cannot make this without using external crates.

Comment: @Fusion there's now const fns which handle a certain number of cases. On nightly there is https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/struct.SyncLazy.html